# Some limitations about EJB 3.0 and Toplink framework

Tags: java, jpa, ejb-3.0, toplink-essentials

I have project use EJB 3.0 and implement Toplink framework for model layer.

When using EJBQL to process data, I see it seems have some limitation:

- It cannot process datatime such as find a part of date such as day, month or year
- It cannot find datetime among from...to
- It cannot comparison datetime field
- It cannot map a class not entity to a customize native select query because I want to get List data from SELECT statement but when I query in case join 2 or more table and map the object output into a class but impossible

> > @PersistenceContext private
> >     EntityManager em;
> >
> > em.createNativeQuery("SELECT
> >     a.usertype , b.username, b.userpass
> >     FROM tablea a, tableb b WHERE a.id =
> >     b.id,MyClass.class).getResultList
> >
> > .....
> >
> > class MyClass(){
> >     String usertype;
> >     String username;
> >     String userpass;
>
> }

Could you help me any ideas?

Thank in advance!

Comment: I'm no TopLink expert but Hibernate does all of the above just fine and (with possible exception of the last item) it's all done within JPA standard; so I'm reasonably sure TopLink does all that as well. Can you describe your issues more specifically?

Answer (score 0):

- It can not, do it in your code. Otherwise, you need to use something database specific on one side of your condition.
- It can, why not. You can use `between :fromDate and :toDate` in the query, or use `> :fromDate` and `< :toDate`, in the `NamedQuery`. Where is the problem.
- It can. Similar to the last one, use `=` sign instead
- It can using `@SqlResultSetMapping`. Refer to [this](http://blog.randompage.org/2006/06/jpa-native-queries.html).